# Increase performance on query with a lot of one-to-many mappings

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, dapper, petapoco

I'm using Entity Framework to SQL Azure and in one page of my application we show quite a bit of related data to the user. We're loading a max of 30 items on the page but each item has 5 one-to-many mappings to other objects. The query time is at a reasonable level but I'm leaking quite a bit of performance on the object mapping. (almost a full second).

Here's an example of what my object looks like

```
public class Task
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public DateTime DueDate {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<TaskData> Data {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> Transactions {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<File> Files {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<People> People {get; set;}
}
```

A task has a name, a status and a due date. It also has **many** TaskData that are custom name/value pairs, **many** Transactions that show a history of the task, **many** Files, **many** Comments and **many** People working on it.

My EF query looks something like this.

```
var Items = context.Items.Include(x=>x.Data).Include(x=>x.Files).Include(x=>x.Comments).Include(x=>x.People).Where(some constraint).ToList();
```

The relevance of a specific task is based first on the status, and then on the due date. So I've created an IComparable override to use with sort. The point is that paged queries don't work well in this scenario because the sort isn't based off of an int or a date (am I right?)

In the rest of our application we're displaying less information about each task and Linq2Entities is working just fine. The object mapping in this case is killing us though. I've gone down the road of going straight to the DB with Dapper but one-to-many mapping has it's caveats. For a few relationships I think it would work well but not for 5-6. My next thing to look at was PetaPoco but I didn't get very far before I thought I'd better throw the question on here first.

Am I crazy for trying to bring back so much data? What are my options for getting maximum performance out of this? I'll take a little bit of complexity since its only one area of the application.

Comment: "Am I crazy for trying to bring back so much data?" Well, you're doing the equivalent of a `SELECT *`. Is that *really* what you need? Or do you just need a few fields from each? If so, projecting onto a view model will be *much* faster.

Comment: No, you're right I only need a few fields. You're saying that instead of .ToList() I should be doing .Select(new TaskViewModel{...}); Does EF compile a more efficient query in that case?

Comment: [Yes, by far.](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/). And that's not the only thing which is faster. Try it!

Comment: Yeah, I'll give it a try. Maybe I was over complicating the problem. I use a ViewModel but don't project directly to it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Craig Stuntz: I am confuzed.. Why can't he use lazy loading and each time he will need something the EF will load it for him?

Comment: @Naor: He could, but the N+1 performance of lazy loading might be the slowest possible option. Lazy loading is why ORMs have a bad reputation for performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am willing to bet your EF query is pulling back too much data. The thing is, the "optimal" retrieval technique heavily depends on the type and amount of data being pulled.

Knowing that up front allows you to tune the queries you run based on your expected data set.

For example ... if you are only pulling a limited number of entities with lots of subentities the pattern I wrote here works well:

[How do I map lists of nested objects with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper)

If you know what ids you are pulling and there are less than 2000, you can shortcut it all by querying a single grid and mapping using `QueryMultiple` eg:

```
cnn.QueryMultiple(@"select * from Tasks where Id in @ids 
select * from Files where TaskId in @ids
.. etc ..", new {ids = new int[] {1,2,3}});
```

If you are yanking a larger set you may need to batch, or do so in phases.

---

For your particular example I would query `Tasks` to get all the task ids and data, then map on the relations using a single `QueryMultiple` to all the associated tables.