# Fill list object using dapper c#

Tags: c#, list, object, fill, dapper

I have two table in my database like this:

[image]

And i have this class:

```
   class Ean
   {
        public string Code{ get; set; }
   }

   class Article
   {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Ean> BarCode { get; set; }
   }

List<Article> arts = new List<Article>();
```

I create a list of article , and with a query using **dapper**. I would like to fill this list with the name of the article but also with a list of related **ean** Article. I try to do this query:

```
SELECT ART.ID AS ID, ART.NAME AS NAME,EAN.EAN AS BARCODE
FROM ART,EAN
WHERE ART.ID = EAN.ID_ART;
```

and in c#..

```
arts = conn.Query<Article>(query, null, transaction).ToList();
```

but don't work. How i can do? Thank's.. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You won't be able to do that in one go. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper?rq=1

Comment: You should be using an inner join here, not a cross join, by the look of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at Dapper's [Multi-Mapping](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) feature.

> Dapper allows you to map a single row to multiple objects. This is a
>   key feature if you want to avoid extraneous querying and eager load
>   associations.

Example:

```
var sql = 
@"select * from #Posts p 
left join #Users u on u.Id = p.OwnerId 
Order by p.Id";

var data = connection.Query<Post, User, Post>(sql, (post, user) => { post.Owner = user; return post;});
var post = data.First();

post.Content.IsEqualTo("Sams Post1");
post.Id.IsEqualTo(1);
post.Owner.Name.IsEqualTo("Sam");
post.Owner.Id.IsEqualTo(99);
```

> Important note Dapper assumes your Id columns are named "Id" or "id",
>   if your primary key is different or you would like to split the wide
>   row at point other than "Id", use the optional 'splitOn' parameter.

Comment: I think this is not correct answer because in this example Owner variable is a User object, not a List<User>. How can I fill List in an object? Thing inverse this, If there is a "posts" list in "user" object, How can we fill posts list?

Comment: I found correct answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748734/793880

Answer (score 4):

Try this, will work I think so

```
arts = conn.Query<Article>(query).ToList();
```

Also you need to change the query as below.

```
SELECT ART.ID AS [Id], ART.NAME AS [Name],EAN.EAN AS [BarCode] 
FROM ART,EAN
WHERE ART.ID = EAN.ID_ART;
```

Comment: it's the same thing i do, but the problem is how to fill the List<Ean> BarCode becouse the query ... EAN.EAN AS BARCODE don't fill it ! How i can do?

Comment: @enzop92 I think you're getting null value in `BarCode`.

Comment: @enzop92 Also can you please `arts = conn.Query<Article,Ean,Ean>(query,(articles, eans) => {articles.Article = articles; return eans;} 
     splitOn: "Code"); 
 ).ToList();`

Answer (score 3):

An other solution, with the benefice of using only one request, just two lines of code, and the possibility of chaining the join (exemple with three tables) :

- Override Equals and GetHashCode for each domain object (this can be do automaticly with inheritance)
- Add two extensions for affect the childrens rows to it's parent's row

Request :

```
var data = connection.Query<Table1, Table2, Table3, Table3>(
        @"  SELECT * FROM Table1
        LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table1Id
        LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table2.Id = Table2Id
        WHERE Table1.Id IN @Ids",
    (t1, t2, t3) => { t2.Table1 = t1; t3.Table2 = t2; return t3; },
    param: new { Ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });

var read = data.GroupBy(t => t.Table2).DoItForEachGroup(gr => gr.Key.Table3s.AddRange(gr)).Select(gr => gr.Key).
    GroupBy(t => t.Table1).DoItForEachGroup(gr => gr.Key.Table2s.AddRange(gr)).Select(gr => gr.Key);
```

Domain objects :

```
public class Table1
{
    public Table1()
    {
        Table2s = new List<Table2>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Table2> Table2s { get; private set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj as Table1 == null) throw new ArgumentException("obj is null or isn't a Table1", "obj");
        return this.Id == ((Table1)obj).Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Table2
{
    public Table2()
    {
        Table3s = new List<Table3>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Table1Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (Table1 == null)
                return default(Guid);
            return Table1.Id;
        }
    }
    public IList<Table3> Table3s { get; private set; }
    public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj as Table2 == null) throw new ArgumentException("obj is null or isn't a Table2", "obj");
        return this.Id == ((Table2)obj).Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Table3
{
    public Table3()
    {

    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid Table2Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (Table2 == null)
                return default(Guid);
            return Table2.Id;
        }
    }
    public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj as Table3 == null) throw new ArgumentException("obj is null or isn't a Table3", "obj");
        return this.Id == ((Table3)obj).Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Extensions :

```
public static class CollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddRange<T>(this IList<T> that, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (that == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("that", "that is null.");
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection", "collection is null.");

        if (that is List<T>)
        {
            ((List<T>)that).AddRange(collection);
            return;
        }

        foreach (T item in collection)
            that.Add(item);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElem>> DoItForEachGroup<TKey, TElem>(this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElem>> group, Action<IGrouping<TKey, TElem>> action)
    {
        if (group == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("group", "group is null.");
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("action", "action is null.");

        group.ToList().ForEach(gr => action(gr));
        return group;
    }
}
```