# Dapper usage with Multi Joins returning multiple children and grandchildren records from ODBC record source

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

Not sure how to do this with Dapper.  I can get parent and multi-children records using this SO item : [How do I map lists of nested objects with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper/17748734#17748734)

How would I adjust this for 3 levels of records.  Or possibly N levels?

Here are my classes....

```
public class T1
{
     public int t1id { get; set; }
     public string f1 {get;set;}
     public List<T2> t2s { get; set; }
}

public class T2
{
    public int t2id { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public string f2 {get; set; }
    public List<T3> t3s {get;set;}
}

public class T3
{
    public int t3id { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public string f3 {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to use dapper to parse a 3 level left join sql statement.

Thanks in advance for your consideration.