# Querying data from multiple tables using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, .net-core, dapper

I have the database table **GTL_TITLES** which has two foreign keys, `AuthorId` and `PublisherId`. If I want to query a title from the database, I want to also get the information from the **AUTHOR** and **PUBLISHER** tables. For this purpose, I created a stored procedure that joins all three tables and selects the following columns:

[image]

My **GtlTitle** Model class looks like this:

```
public string ISBN { get; set; }
public string VolumeName { get; set; }
public string TitleDescription { get; set; }
public string PublisherName { get; set; }    
public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
public Author TitleAuthor { get; set; }
public Publisher Publisher { get; }
```

As you could have guessed, class **Author** has two strings: `FirstName` and `LastName` and **Publisher** has `PublisherName`.

These being said, this is the method calling the database:

```
public GtlTitle GetTitle(string ISBN)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            return connection.QuerySingle<GtlTitle>("GetTitleByISBN", new { ISBN }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }
```

And returns the following: `{"isbn":"978-0-10074-5","volumeName":"Volume Name - 97581","titleDescription":"Description - 97581","publisherName":"Publisher - 714","publicationDate":"2020-05-23T00:00:00","titleAuthor":null,"publisher":null}`

As you can see, `titleAuthor` and `publisher` are null. How can I fix this? Will I need to write fields like `public string FirstName` in the **GtlTitle** model class instead or is there any way of populating the **Author** and **Publisher**
 as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I map lists of nested objects with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper)

Comment: @Crowcoder This is not a case for nesting, more like a one to one mapping.

Comment: Looks like a complex object query. You just need to tell Dapper where each object is. See this link: https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/44980945/querying-into-a-complex-object-with-dapper

Comment: @Alex `splitOn` is mentioned a couple of times in the link I posted.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes it is mentioned but the author of the current question doesn't have a nested relationship, just a simple one-to-one map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper supports multimapping with the `splitOn` parameter where you can split a row into mulitple objects by providing the column names where a new object  begins.

```
return connection.Query<GtlTitle, Author, Publisher, GtlTitle>(sql,
    (g,a,p) => { 
                 g.TitleAuthor = a; 
                 g.Publisher = p; 
                 return g; }, 
    splitOn: "FirstName,PublisherName").First();
```