# Map to nested object using Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have an object that has 2 lists of classes.

```
public class Order
{
    int order_id;
    double amount;
    List<order_item> order_items;
    List<order_shipment> order_shipments;
}
```

And here's how the objects should be mapped:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Order_Items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
INNER JOIN Order_Shipments s ON s.order_id = o.order_id
```

What's a way to map the above query to the nested class?

Comment: Have you looked at dapper multi-mapper?

Comment: Is that a separate library? I'm not familiar with it

Answer (score 2):

Give it a go:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
conn.Query<Order, order_item, order_shipment, Order>(@"
        SELECT o.*,i.*,s.* FROM Orders o
        INNER JOIN Order_Items i ON i.order_id = o.order_id
        INNER JOIN Order_Shipments s ON s.order_id = o.order_id 
    ", (o, i, s) => {
        Order order;
        
        if (!lookup.TryGetValue(o.order_id, out order))
              lookup.Add(o.order_id, order = o);
        
        order.order_items = order.order_items ?? new List<order_item>();
        order.order_items.Add(i);
         
        order.order_shipments = order.order_shipments ?? new List<order_shipment>();
        order.order_shipments.Add(s);
        
        return order;
    }).AsQueryable();
    
var result = lookup.Values;
```

See: [How do I map lists of nested objects with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper)

**Update:**

Thanks, **@Palle Due** for pointing out. You should also add `splitOn` parameter based on first column of tables as follows:(Assuming first column of `Order_Items` is `order_item_id` and `Order_Shipment` is `order_shipment_id`)

```
 splitOn: "order_id, order_item_id, order_shipment_id"
```

See: [Correct use of Multimapping in Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper)

Comment: Aren't you missing `splitOn: "order_id"`? The default is to split on columns named `id`, so `Query` wouldn't know how to separate.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand exactly what you have said. Could you elaborate it a bit, please?

Comment: The `Query` needs some help splitting the result data into Orders, order_items and order_shipments. You do this by adding the `splitOn` parameter stating which columns make up the split. You haven't added that parameter, which is fine, but only if all split columns are named `id`. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper