# Incorrect mapping with Dapper, .NET Core and Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, dapper

Thanks in advance.  I'm seeing an issue with my mapping using Postgres and Dapper.  I'm trying to map an Organization object, which has a one-to-many relationship with the Location object. The following is my mapping code:

```
public Organization GetOrganizationById(long id)
        {
            var query = @"SELECT 
                 o.organization_id,
                 o.guid,
                 o.name,
                 o.is_active,
                 o.created,
                 l.location_id,
                 l.org_id,
                 l.guid,
                 l.internal_identifier,
                 l.name,
                 l.address,
                 l.city,
                 l.state,
                 l.zip,
                 l.phonenumber,
                 l.is_active,
                 l.opendate,
                 l.closedate,
                 l.created
                FROM organization AS o
                 INNER JOIN location as l 
                    ON o.organization_id = l.org_id
                 WHERE o.organization_id = @Id";

            using (var con = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {

                var orgResult = con.Query<Organization, List<Location>, Organization>(
                    query,
                    (org, locations) =>
                    {
                        org.Locations = locations;
                        return org;
                    },
                    new {Id = id},
                    splitOn: "location_id").FirstOrDefault();
                
                
                return orgResult;
            }
        }
```

I have the following objects created:

```
    public class Organization
    {
        public long OrganizationId { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid { get;set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        
        //[JsonIgnore]
        public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
        
    }
```

and

```
    public class Location
    {
        public long LocationId { get; set; }
        public long OrgId { get; set; }
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public string InternalIdentifier { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime OpenDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CloseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    }
```

Now the issue is, when I get the results it's not even close to accurate. Though the query when copied into a SQL client it's returning the correct results.

Here's what I see in the JSON response along with what's incorrect:

```
{
  "organizationId": 0, // This is incorrect. The organization ID is one (this appears to be the default int/long)
  "guid": "4fc55437-8497-4388-be48-c6b8c5dfee93", // This is correct
  "name": "TestOrg", // This is correct
  "isActive": false, // This is incorrect. Both locations are active, as is the organization
  "created": "2021-01-27T05:20:42.287925", // This is correct 
  "locations": [] // Incorrect, there should be two locations present
}
```

Anyway, is there anything you think I'm missing with the mapping that would prevent these records from not mapping to their POCOs correctly?

Comment: You got duplicated column names. Dapper needs unique column names. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65992611/dapper-nested-objects/65994905#65994905 And column names need to match exactly, `organization_id` has an underscore

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface - is there some form of annotation I can add to set the column name? Having to have things like unique "created" and "isActive" fields seems like somewhat of a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dapper requires your model property names to mirror your table (not case sensitive).

- You can try using the `[ColumnName()]` attribute above your properties. I've heard this works for some but it didn't for me. I ended up using AutoMapper and created a mapper object.

```cs
[ColumnName("SomeFieldName")]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Before you look into that (cause it's a pain) try using Dapper's `QueryMultiple()` method.

[Dapper's Query Multiple](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple)

You may have to play around with it a bit. It's been awhile since I've written the full `QueryMultiple()` method the Dapper way. I made a wrapper class to containerize my dapper functions (I just containerize all 3rd party packages incase of exceptions or something). Here's one of my methods using `QueryMultiple().` to return 2 data sets using `out` parameters. You can adjust this to return as may sets as you need.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Executes a query with multiple results and stores the result sets in the out parameters.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T1">The type of the first result set.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T2">The type of the second result set.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="P">The parameter type. Generally an autonomous/dynamic object, a <see cref="DynamicParameters"/>, or an <see cref="ExpandoObject"/>.</typeparam>
/// <param name="sql">The SQL query string or stored procedure.</param>
/// <param name="parameters">The parameter(s) for the stored procedure.</param>
/// <param name="results1">The first result set.</param>
/// <param name="results2">The second result set.</param>
/// <param name="queryType">
/// <para>The query's command type.</para>
/// Defaults to <strong><see cref="CommandType.StoredProcedure"/></strong>.
/// </param>
public void ExecuteQueryMultiple<T1, T2, P>(string sql, P parameters, 
    ConnStringKey connectionKey, // This is a personal app setting enum...
    out List<T1> results1, out List<T2> results2, 
    CommandType queryType = CommandType.StoredProcedure)
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = new 
        SqlConnection(configurations.GetConnectionString(connectionKey)))
    {
        using (SqlMapper.GridReader sqlReader = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, 
            parameters, commandType: queryType, commandTimeout: ConnectionTimeout))
        {
            results1 = sqlReader.Read<T1>().AsList();
            results2 = sqlReader.Read<T2>().AsList();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use something similar if your SQL was like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    o.organization_id,
    o.guid,
    o.name,
    o.is_active,
    o.created,
FROM organization AS o
WHERE o.organization_id  = @Id

SELECT
    l.location_id,
    l.org_id,
    l.guid,
    l.internal_identifier,
    l.name,
    l.address,
    l.city,
    l.state,
    l.zip,
    l.phonenumber,
    l.is_active,
    l.opendate,
    l.closedate,
    l.created
FROM location AS l
WHERE l.org_id = @Id
```

Of course, then you'd have to aggregate the two result sets in the code.

---

Usage:

```cs
var someParams = new { Id = someId };

sql = "your sql";

_sql.ExecuteQueryMultiple<Organization, Location, dynamic>(
    sql, someParams, 
    // this is an enum of mine that ties back to my appsettings.json or app.config file to get the connection string
    MyConfigurationConnectionKey, 
    out List<Organization> organizations, 
    out List<Location> locations, 
    CommandType.Text);

// Aggregate the two data sets...
organizations.Locations = locations; // or however you need to do it
```