# Lookup on multiple table using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Following the answer on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17748734/12518882

I've used the solution and it work perfect. The only things I don't understand is why i can use the Syncronous way and not the Asyncronous.
I try to use `await con.QueryAsync<>` it give me an error: "Task<IEnumerable> doen't contain a definition for AsQueryable.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

`await con.QueryAsync<>` returns a `Task` which represents the asynchronous operation itself, not the result of the method you're calling. So you're attempting to call `.AsQueryable()` on type `Task` .

You can convert your awaited results like this:

```
var results = await connection.QueryAsync<A, B, A>(
        "your sql query",
         (a, b) =>
         {    
            //Perform operations

            return a;
         });          

 return results.AsQueryable();
```